# Analytics API: Query for when objects are tagged?

Tags: rally

Is it possible using the Analytics API to query for when a particular type of artifact, like a defect or test case, was tagged with a particular tag?

What would the query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ObjectID of your Tag of interest is 12345678910, then a query similar to the following should do the trick:

```
    "_TypeHierarchy":"TestCase",
    "Tags":{$in:[12345678910]},
    "_PreviousValues.Tags":{$nin:[12345678910]}
```